# iText (5 and below) doesn't honor 'type' attribute for ordered lists in HTML

Tags: itext, itext7

When using iText2, we discovered that the 'type' attribute for Ordered Lists (and possibly Unordered Lists as well) was not honored.

I've been experimenting with iText5 (the last version that supports PDF generation from HTML), and it also does not honor the 'type' attribute.  Debugging into the iText5 library, I noticed that the 'type' attribute is ignored - the only way to get it to work is to replace it with a value in the 'style' attribute.

That is:

```
<ol type='a'>
```

... does NOT work, but:

```
<ol style='list-type-style: lower-alpha'>
```

... DOES work.

Given that this bug has remained in the codebase over many iterations, is it something that was omitted by accident, or on purpose?

I realize that the newest version of iText - iText7 - does not provide HTML-to-PDF support, but I would like to know why this was omitted in iText5 and before, and, also, if HTML-to-PDF support is re-added, to assure that it will be fixed.

Comment: This is not a technical question, or a question that can be answered in a technical way. If you want to know *why* a certain feature is missing from a product, or if that feature will be available in the next version of the product (iText 7 html2pdf is expected for 2017), then StackOverflow is not the best place to ask. I recommend that you contact iText directly: http://itextpdf.com/contact

Comment: It is omitted because over all those years nobody asked for it. You don't bake carrot cake if you know that no one is going to eat it, do you? If you need this feature, claiming that "it's a bug" is probably the worst way to win the sympathy of the iText developers. As Amedee already explained, you can contact the developers, or better yet: submit a code contribution that adds support for the feature you want.

Comment: All I can say is, the "type" attribute for the OL tag is standard HTML that's been around for a very long time; iText (5 and before) are advertised as supporting HTML-to-PDF generation, so if it's missing an essential (tho' small) bit of the HTML spec, I'd call that the very definition of a "bug".  Since iText is now a paid-for product, shouldn't such bugs (or oversights, or whatever you want to call it) be fixed?  I could understand your attitude if this were a free, open-source project (as it apparently used to be), but not in its current paid-for state.

Comment: iText was never intended or advertised as a full implementation of the entire HTML spec. It's hard enough to implement the full PDF spec. It does however implement a subset of the HTML spec, mostly based on what iText developers thought people would use most, and based on customer feedback. iText is only a paid-for product if you can't open source your own code, and that's not a technical subject, so Stack Overflow moderators would flag that as off topic.

Comment: In the case I'm hoping to use iText in, the product would not be open source, and thus we'd have to pay for iText.  But thanks for letting me know the details on that.

In any case, I had thought that it was a reasonably full HTML implementation (where the "type" attribute for OL tags would be considered by most to be part of a reasonably full implementation).

Comment: In any case, I'm currently working on fixing that omission myself, and will report back if I have a fix for you, should you want it.

Incidentally, the calculation done for implementation of list-type-style for alphabetic list types is also incorrect - there's an off-by-one issue where instead of 'w, x, y, z, a", instead "w, x, y, a@, a" is generated.

If this is not the appropriate venue for this discussion, can you recommend a better one that has a public face?  It would seem to me that solving this technical problem would be appropriate in this technical forum, no?

Comment: @tbessie, answering the last part of your question, this will be supported in `iText7 html2Pdf` starting right from the first public release. Meanwhile, I am voting to close this question because it is more of a bug report than a programming question.